# Proving a formula for $\sum ^{n}_{k=1}\sin kt$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

> Let $t$ be a real number such that $\sin \dfrac{t}{2}\neq 0$.  Show that
>
> $$\sum ^{n}_{k=1}\sin kt=\dfrac{\cos\dfrac{t}{2}-\cos \left( n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right) t}{2\sin \dfrac{t}{2}}$$
> for every positive $n$. What method should I use?

Any explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Multiply and divide by $\sin t/2$ and then try to make a telescopic sum.

Comment: See the question ["How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409). The limits of summation are different, and the answer there differs in form from the answer you seek, but the approaches are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Plug $z=\cos t+i \sin t$ in
$$1+z+z^2+...+z^n=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$$

and equate real and imaginary parts!

Note: In this method, we also get the formula for $\sum_k \cos kt$

Answer (score 3):

Just an application of the formula **Product-to-Sum**

### $$
2 \sin \theta \sin \varphi=\cos (\theta-\varphi)-\cos (\theta+\varphi)
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin k t \\
=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2 \sin \frac{t}{2} \cdot \sin k t}{2 \sin \frac{t}{2}} \\
=& \frac{\left.\sum_{k=1}^{n} [\cos \left(k t-\frac{t}{2}\right)-\cos \left(k t+\frac{t}{2}\right)\right]}{2 \sin \frac{t}{2}} \\
=& \frac{\cos \frac{t}{2}-\cos \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) t}{2 \sin \frac{t}{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$